# C++ 11: is a defaulted copy constructor user declared?

Tags: c++, c++11

I guess it is so, but I am looking for C++11 language lawyers to confirm my impression. Is it true that the following class

```
struct X{
X(){}
X(X const&)=default;
};
```

will not be automatically move-enabled, i.e., getting `X(X&&)` and `operator=(X&&)`, because its copy constructor is "user-declared", even though it looks equivalent to

```
struct X{
};
```

which will get both `X(X const&)` and `X(X&&)` etc., implicitely declared and (trivially) defined on use.

Comment: Thanks for helping me avoiding writing bullshit in my upcoming C++ book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `default`ed copy constructor *is* indeed "user-declared"; I think the addition of `default` was in fact the reason why they changed the term from "user-defined" to "user-declared".

Answer (score 3):

From the standard:

> #### 8.4.2 Explicitly-defaulted functions [dcl.fct.def.default]
>
> 4 - [...] A special member function is user-provided if it is user-declared and not explicitly
>   defaulted or deleted on its ﬁrst declaration. [...]

An explicit default can be combined with its declaration, or it can be separate:

```
struct S {
    S();
};
S::S() = default;
```

In either case its (first) declaration makes it user-declared.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your defaulted copy assign operator precludes the implicit move ctor.

BTW putting `=default` is actually a *definition*.  I remember [trying to implement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9020372/how-do-i-use-unique-ptr-for-pimpl) a pimpl idiom with `std::unique_ptr` and having to remove `=default` from headers and putting them in the implementation file because the destructor for `unique_ptr` needed the definition of the class it is trying to clean up.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct, §12.8 sets the conditions when a move constructor gets implicitly declared and the presence of a user-declared copy constructor precludes that. You cannot have

- user-declared copy constructor
- user-declared copy assignment operator
- user-declared move-assignment operator
- user-declared destructor