# Why would you want to put a class in an implementation file?

Tags: c++, class

While looking over some code, I ran into the following:

.h file

```
class ExampleClass
{
public:
    // methods, etc
private:
    class AnotherExampleClass* ptrToClass;
}
```

.cpp file

```
class AnotherExampleClass
{
    // methods, etc
}

// AnotherExampleClass and ExampleClass implemented
```

Is this a pattern or something beneficial when working in c++?  Since the class is not broken out into another file, does this work flow promote faster compilation times?

or is this just the style this developer?

Comment: `methods, etc` being declarations or definitions?

Comment: @MadPhysicist the guts of the class.  I didn't put anything in because it doesn't really relate to the problem.

Comment: Pimpl idiom. This is used to avoid long compilation times. And also sometimes for a sort of binary compatibility. The `AnotherExampleClass` class is an implementation detail.

Comment: An awful kind of pimple idiom. There are better ways. I guess your developer lives in the past

Comment: @BЈовић - do you have any examples of better ways?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9020372/how-do-i-use-unique-ptr-for-pimpl

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is variously known as the [pImpl Idiom](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom), Cheshire cat technique, or Compilation firewall.

> Benefits:
>
> - Changing private member variables of a class does not require recompiling classes that depend on it, thus make times are faster, and
>     the FragileBinaryInterfaceProblem is reduced.
> - The header file does not need to #include classes that are used 'by value' in private member variables, thus compile times are faster.
> - This is sorta like the way SmallTalk automatically handles classes... more pure encapsulation.
>
> Drawbacks:
>
> - More work for the implementor.
> - Doesn't work for 'protected' members where access by subclasses is required.
> - Somewhat harder to read code, since some information is no longer in the header file.
> - Run-time performance is slightly compromised due to the pointer indirection, especially if function calls are virtual (branch prediction for indirect branches is generally poor).

Herb Sutter's "Exceptional C++" books also go into useful detail on the appropriate usage of this technique.

Comment: Thanks for all the resources!  I figured it was something along those lines, but I didn't know about the "pImpl Idiom".

Comment: Yeah, once you know the name for it, it's easy to learn everything else about it.

Answer (score 11):

The most common example would be when using the PIMPL pattern or similar techniques. Still, there are other uses as well. Typically, the distinction .hpp/.cpp in C++ is rather (or, at least can be) one of public interface versus private implementation. If a type is only used as part of the implementation, then that's a good reason not to export it in the header file.

Answer (score 7):

Apart from possibly being an implementation of the PIMPL idiom, here are two more possible reason to do this:

Objects in C++ cannot modify their `this` pointer. As a consequence, they cannot change type in mid-usage. However, `ptrToClass` can change, allowing an implementation to `delete` itself and to replace itself with another instance of another subclass of `AnotherExampleClass`.

If the implementation of `AnotherExampleClass` depends on some template parameters, but the interface of `ExampleClass` does not, it is possible to use a template derived from `AnotherExampleClass` to provide the implementation. This hides part of the necessary, yet internal type information from the user of the interface class.